# Share Sharepoint site with entire external domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have a request in from a staff member who wishes to share external guest access to a Sharepoint site with all users in another company domain. This other company domain does not use O365 and more than likely do not have their individual email accounts configured as Microsoft accounts.

**Example:** 
Share domainxyz.sharepoint.com/sites/sharethis with all users in domain123.com

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. SharePoint external guest access is done on a email-by-email address basis.